# Help With Notation In Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: logic, notation

The following is the notation for Fermat's Last Theorem

$\neg\exists_{\{a,b,c,n\},(a,b,c,n)\in(\mathbb{Z}^+)\color{blue}{^4}\land n>2\land abc\neq 0}a^n+b^n=c^n$

I understand everything in the notation besides the 4 highlighted in blue. Can someone explain to me what this means?

Comment: What an ugly way to formulate a great theorem!

Comment: If $S$ is a set, $S^4$ denotes the four-fold Cartesian product of $S$ with itself, $S\times S \times S \times S$, which is the set of (ordered) quadruples whose components are elements of $S$. Here, $S = \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Note that under the usual meaning assigned to $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ the $abc\ne 0$ part is superfluous.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sometimes $\mathbb Z^+$ means "non-negative", though I  don't recommend this usage. According to these sources, "positive" is distinguished from "*strictly* positive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $(\mathbb Z^+)^4$ is just the set of tuples of $4$ positive integers. So, it says that $(a,b,c,n)$ is a tuple of $4$ positive integers. It would be equally clear to write $a\in\mathbb Z^+,b\in\mathbb Z^+,c\in\mathbb Z^+,n\in\mathbb Z^+$ or even to write $a,b,c,n\in\mathbb Z^+$ - all of which are equivalent. The author is likely looking to emphasize that Fermat's theorem is a statement about the non-existence of such a $4$-tuple by writing it that way - i.e. they're making the domain very explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Cartesian product,
$$ (\mathbb{Z}^{+}) \times (\mathbb{Z}^{+}) \times (\mathbb{Z}^{+}) \times (\mathbb{Z}^{+}), $$
normally abbreviated as $(\mathbb{Z}^{+})^4$.

Answer (score 1):

The set of all $4$-tuples of positive integers.

A single element is a $1$-tuple, an ordered pair is a $2$-tuple, and an ordered foursome is a four-tuple. So it's the set:

$$\left({\mathbb Z^+}\right)^4 = \left \{{(a,b,c,d): a, b, c, d \in \mathbb Z^+}\right\}$$

Where $(a,b,c,d) = (e,f,g,h)$ if and only if $a = e, b = f, c = g, d = h$.

You can also think of it as the set of all sequences of length four whose image is positive integers. This would be a function that maps $0 \mapsto a ,1 \mapsto b, 2 \mapsto c$, and $3 \mapsto d$.